# Insert (append) memo lines to database using a parameter

Tags: sql, delphi

How can you append cxmemo1 text into a database field (which is memo type) which already contains data ? 
If I use :

> DataModule2.T2.Params.ParamByName('a3').Value := cxmemo1.Text;

the prior text just gets overwritten. How can I just append it ?

This is a part of an update query.

Comment: That is your SQL? You can try something like `Update table set Fielda3 = Fielda3 + :a3 where key = :key`

Comment: Do you know the previous value? Then you could just use `DataModule2.T2.Params.ParamByName('a3').Value := previousValue + cxmemo1.Text;`

Comment: dont know previous value

Comment: @David A using set Fielda3 = Fielda3 + :a3 replaces all text with a '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your update query you may use something like this :

```
update TABLE t set 
  t.MY_MEMO_FIELD = Coalesce(MY_MEMO_FIELD,'') || :a3 
where t.ID = :PKey
```

Update: 
I added `Coalesce` in case of old value is null.

Comment: yes Val, this seems to work. Problem is the text gets appended right to the previous one. Is there a way I can add a cariage return and some custom text so I can see the difference between previous and newly appended text?

Comment: Why the sub select needed?

Comment: @user763539 `(SELECT Coalesce(MY_MEMO_FIELD,'') from TABLE where ID = :PKey) || ASCII_CHAR(13) || ASCII_CHAR(10) || :P or (SELECT Coalesce(MY_MEMO_FIELD,'') from TABLE where ID = :PKey) || CHAR(13)||CHAR(10)...` You can also add something else as marker ..

Comment: @kobik subselect is to get old value of field

Comment: The "old"\original value is `MY_MEMO_FIELD`. e.g. `MY_MEMO_FIELD = MY_MEMO_FIELD || :P`. or am I missing anything?

Comment: Val, can I have the old code back before you changed it?

Comment: @kobik Yes you are right. It is. this comment mislead me : "@David A using set Fielda3 = Fielda3 + :a3 replaces all text with a '0'"

Comment: @user763539 update TABLE t set 
  t.MY_MEMO_FIELD = (SELECT MY_MEMO_FIELD from TABLE where ID = :PKey) || :a3 
where t.ID = :PKey . This is the old code.

Comment: @user763539 cleck the "edited at (time)" link below the answer - and you would get the full history of the adjustments of it